# Could not get token Access Denied with AWS IAM Authenticator

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam

I'm trying to setup AWS IAM Authenticator for my k8s cluster. I have two AWS account: A and B.

The k8s account runs in the B account.

I have created in the A account the following resources:

**Policy**

```
Description: Grants permissions to assume the kubernetes-admin role
Policy:
  Statement:
    - Action: sts:*
      Effect: Allow
      Resource: arn:aws:iam::<AccountID-B>:role/kubernetes-admin
      Sid: KubernetesAdmin
  Version: 2012-10-17
```

The policy is associated to a group and I add my IAM user to the group.

in the B account I have created the following role:

```
AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
  Statement:
    - Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Effect: Allow
      Principal:
        AWS: arn:aws:iam::<AccountID-A>:root
  Version: 2012-10-17
```

This is the `ConfigMap` to configure aws-iam-authenticator:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.yaml: |
    # a unique-per-cluster identifier to prevent replay attacks
    # (good choices are a random token or a domain name that will be unique to your cluster)
    clusterID: k8s.mycluster.net
    server:
      # each mapRoles entry maps an IAM role to a username and set of groups
      # Each username and group can optionally contain template parameters:
      # "{{AccountID}}" is the 12 digit AWS ID.
      # "{{SessionName}}" is the role session name.
      mapRoles:
      - roleARN: arn:aws:iam::<AccountID-B>:role/kubernetes-admin
        username: kubernetes-admin:{{AccountID}}:{{SessionName}}
        groups:
        - system:masters
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-12-13T19:41:39Z
  labels:
    k8s-app: aws-iam-authenticator
  name: aws-iam-authenticator
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "87401"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/aws-iam-authenticator
  uid: 1bc39653-ff0f-11e8-a580-02b4590539ba
```

The kubeconfig is:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <certificate>
    server: https://api.k8s.mycluster.net
  name: k8s.mycluster.net
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: k8s.mycluster.net
    namespace: kube-system
    user: k8s.mycluster.net
  name: k8s.mycluster.net
current-context: k8s.mycluster.net
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: k8s.mycluster.net
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env:
      - name: "AWS_PROFILE"
        value: "myaccount"
      args:
        - "token"
        - "-i"
        - "k8s.mycluster.net"
        - "-r"
        - "arn:aws:iam::<AccountID-B>:role/kubernetes-admin"
```

The result is:

```
could not get token: AccessDenied: Access denied
    status code: 403, request id: 6ceac161-ff2f-11e8-b263-2b0e32831969
Unable to connect to the server: getting token: exec: exit status 1
```

Any idea? I don't get what i'm missing.

Comment: What are you using to provision the cluster? You need to set up the Kubernetes API Server to include aws-iam-authenticator as an auth method.

Comment: I've solved the issue. I'll reply down with the solution

Comment: Please post the solution so it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 6):

to add to this - my solution was to do the following:

in ~/.kube directory:

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name eks-dev-cluster --role-arn=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

this creates a file config-my-eks-cluster

```
vi config-my-eks-cluster
```

comment out the two lines mentioned above:

```
  apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
  args:
  - token
  - -i
  - eks-dev-cluster
  #- -r
  #- arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/eks-dev-role (the role you made for eks)
  command: aws-iam-authenticator
```

Then make sure you export your user profile with:

export AWS_PROFILE=XXXXXXXXX  (the user you used to create the cluster in the console or through the cli)

The run:

```
kubectl get svc --v=10
```

this will put output into verbose mode and give you details on any errors that creep up.

Answer (score 2):

the way to make it work properly is to remove

```
- "-r"
- "arn:aws:iam::<AccountID-B>:role/kubernetes-admin"
```

and pass the role to assume to the `AWS_PROFILE` env var